# AJAX query to get json data returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httpresponse

I'm trying to get JSON data from URL but for some, I'm getting a successful result and for some, I'm getting undefined. For instance, the below code results in undefined output when printed to the console:
(The below examples are just for reference and not real-world data on which I'm working on)

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos',
    dataType: 'json',
    
    success:function(response){
        myArray = response.data
        // buildTable(myArray)
        console.log(myArray)
    }
})
```

And the same code prints correct output for different json URL :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    
    success:function(response){
        myArray = response.data
        // buildTable(myArray)
        console.log(myArray)
    }
})
```

The same issue I'm facing while getting response data on the actual URL I'm working on. Is there any solution for this so that I can render the correct result? I need to get JSON from the URL and then convert it to HTML output but I'm stuck in the very first step where I need to get data from the URL.

Comment: There's no `data` property in the Github API response. What were you expecting it to print?

Comment: The github API returns an array of objects, not a single object. Try `console.log(response[0].full_name)` for instance.

Comment: You can't assume that every API returns the same kind of object. Every API is different, since it returns data appropriate for that query. You have to read the documentation and look at sample results to see how to access values in the JSON.

Comment: So there's no reason to expect there to be a `.data` property in an arbitrary response.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I used jquery instead and it worked for me. In my application, I'm reading from endpoints, extracting data for specific keys, and displaying it in a table that is created on the fly with respective header columns. Thanks a million for your help with this Barner!

Comment: Instead of what? The code in the question uses jQuery.

Comment: Instead of using the above code, I used predicates in amalgamation with jquery library functions to achieve what I did. I can't write the complete code here to show what I did.

Comment: The above code uses jQuery `$.ajax()`. Are you talking about the `buildTable()` function?

Comment: I don't see how that would solve the problem that `response.data` is `undefined` in the first code.

Comment: This solution worked for me for the actual URL I was trying out for - 
var myArray = []
const urlVariable= [_url_];
 myArray = fetch(urlVariable).then((response) => response.json()).then((data)=>{
  return data;
 })

Comment: So your solution is to remove the reference to the `.data` property, which is exactly what I said the problem was.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million for your help with this. Really appreciate you taking the time to look at my problem and providing the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short way of doing the same without jQuery:

```js
// const url="https://reqres.in/api/users";
const url="https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos";
fetch(url).then(r=>r.json()).then(dat=>dat.forEach(d=>console.log(d.full_name)))
```

And - for those of us who are using jQuery anyway - here it is in the jQuery way:

```js
// const url="https://reqres.in/api/users";
const url="https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos";
$.getJSON(url,dat=>dat.forEach(d=>console.log(d.full_name)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may _work_, it doesn't explain what the problem was with OP's code (and it wasn't anything to do with jQuery)

Comment: Yes, I used JQuery instead of Ajax and it worked for me. Thanks a million for your help with this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Carsten Massmann: I've marked your answer as the best answer since jquery worked for my requirement. Thank You!

Comment: @viveksingh — If jQuery worked why are you accepting an answer that doesn't use jQuery? Or explain what the problem was? You don't *have* to accept an answer if there isn't one that actually addresses the problem. Doing so just leaves confusing information for anyone finding this page in the future.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it worked for me.

Comment: of course with a little tweak here and there.